# Spotfire split function

Tags: function, split, spotfire

I hope someone could help me with this thanks

I used characters ()() to split out into a new column to capture specific information for example ()info 1(), this works fine the new column now has info 1 as expected however the characters ()() needs be used more than once so when ()info 2() is entered it over writes info 1. is there a way to stop this from happening so it keeps a running history?

example of what I have

1.Case
2.when Trim(Split([column name],"()",2))!='0' Then Trim(Split([column name],"()",2))

3.End

Comment: can you clarify what using ()() more than once means? Are you saying that new information periodically overwrites [column name]?

Comment: Its the information between the two ()() special characters that I use to pull specific information out of a comment field. For example ()Apples() and ()Pears().. I have a column named additional comments and from that column I want to pull all information about fruits into a new column in this case Apples, Pears at any time the additional comment field can be updated to add new fruits ()Orange() therefore I would want to see all 3 in my new column. however  each new entry overwrites the other, if I had the 3 mentioned fruits only Orange will be showing.

Comment: given that you use the same marker () for start and end of the field to capture, I cannot think of a way of distinguishing what is between the ()..() versus what is outside them. For instance in the comment "we have ()Apples() or ()Pears() or maybe ()Passion Fruit() " there is no way I can think of to tell that it is "Apples" and "Pears" and "Passion Fruit" that are inside the markers, it could well be " or "  and " or  maybe ", unless you have more specific rules to detect what is inside the ()...().

Comment: ok thanks for your input, so im going back to the drawing board :).